# VBA (Excel) to Powerpoint Automatization (in a big Production)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, freeze

i got another issue on one of my big production lines. The Tool is computing different financial Kpis and Charts and copy them into a Powerpoint, after that every PPTx is saved.

All this happens local on my machine. I open the Powerpoint instance outside the big loop and giving the Powerpoint object as an parameter into the function needed.

```
Public PowerPointApp as object

Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

call copyChartsToPptx(PowerPointApp)
```

There i check if the instance is still available, if not i create a new instance an open the template in order to fill it.

```
Set PowerpointTest = GetObject(, "PowerPointApp.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    Set Powerpoint = CreateObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PowerpointTest = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    Err.Clear  

End If
```

This Setup runs very smooth, even when i simulate a pptx freeze (just by closing it) everything works fine an he continues to reopen the pptx instance an use it.

Now the weird part: after a random number of produced Presentations ( 150, 240, 400, 300 usw.), PPTX just freezes and the Production Stops ... this happens when the skript try to copy Charts from excel into the PPTX

```
'Performance Chart mifid kopieren
Sprungmarke3:
Workbooks("Mischungstool_4.0.xlsm").Worksheets("temp_mifid").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("temp_mifid").ChartObjects("Per_mifid").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("temp_mifid").ChartObjects("Per_mifid").Copy

    'Einfügen
    On Error Resume Next
    With ppPres.Slides(32).Shapes.Paste
        .Left = 40
        .Top = 150
    End With

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    errorCounter = errorCounter + 1
   
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Err.Clear
    GoTo Sprungmarke3

End If
```

The thing is, when i just let the error Handler go for ever  in this Loop he freezes, but when i click into the powerpoint he continues to Produce the Files corecctly.

But when i try t catch this error an restart the loop at the same position, he just continues to produce the PPTX but without copy the charts ... (the KPIS in tables an everything elese works fine)

This is a very strange behaviour ...so my questions are:

1. how can i check if powerpoint is still reacting or frozen
2. how can i copy charts from excel to VBA without loosing the Powerpoint connection after a couple of hundred Loops
3. Does anyone else encounterd such problems in a huge production line
4. Early Binding is much slower and will trigger the error much more frequent

If you need any further information or code feel free to ask...

Thank you a thousand times !!
Fabian

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation to be able to test, but I'd guess you need to move Sprungmarke3: further down to just before On Error Resume Next. Otherwise, every time the macro times out, it starts over with selecting and copying the chart, which wastes time unproductively. Your timing problem is probably only with the paste operation, not selecting and copying. In addition, I doubt you need to activate and select the chart to copy it, that's another time-waster.

Comment: Have you copied your code correctly on this line `Set PowerpointTest = GetObject(, "PowerPointApp.Application")`? i.e. you've written **PowerPointApp** rather than **PowerPoint**. I imagine that would trigger your error handling code every time.

Comment: what I would do  try is to give some time between activating and copying.  and some time between copying and pasting. Now this slows the whole thing down quite a lot but it is the only way I have to prevent such issues as yours:
    timestamp = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
    While Now() < timestamp
        DoEvents
    Wend